# Android - Get the title/position/duration of the video currently playing in another app

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an idea of the app which will listen for metadata of the currently playing video in another app (Netflix for example) and analyze this metadata. For example, when user starts playing a movie in his Netflix app I want to request some IMDB-based information about this movie in my own running app. In order to do this I need some metadata, the title of the movie at least or anything else. If in addition to the static metadata it's possible to listen for any other lifetime data like the current position/duration, playing/paused states it would be great.

The questions are as follows:

1. Do you think it's possible at any Android (mobile/TV) platform?
2. If it's possible technically, doesn't it violate any rules?

I'd appreciate any links or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless other apps expose that, you can't do that on non modified Android.